# How to add Pandas dataframe column from a element of a list in another column without lambda?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this dataframe

```
A                           B
[ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' ]         3
[ 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h']    5
```

How can I create a new column such as below without lambda?

```
A                                 B   C
[ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' ]               3   'b'
[ 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' ]         5   'g'
```

If using lambda, it will be

```
df['C'] = df['A'].apply( lambda x : x[-2] )
```

EDIT:
Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
mydata = [ { 'A' : [ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' ] ,       'B' : 3 } ,
           { 'A' : [ 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' ] , 'B' : 5}]
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
```

Comment: Good question. It would be even better, if you provided the entire working code.

Comment: That's already all code. What more information do you want to know?

Comment: It's not Python code. It's pseudo code. You don't define df anywhere or import pandas anywhere. Probably not an issue for people that unlike me are very familiar with pandas.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to avoid lambdas?

Comment: You're talking about creating a new column `C` but where does the `'h'` come from in the `A` column in your example? Please fix if it's wrong, that's super misleading.

Comment: @GeneBurinsky the new column, C, will be populated by the 2nd to the last  item of the list in column A

Comment: You could try a list comprehension approach that should be faster than a lambda.  Assuming that performance is the reason you want to avoid a lambda

Comment: tommy Gene, added the example code for you

Comment: @BobHaffner, yes, it's for the speed. In the example df has 2 rows only. But in my real application it can be more than 1 million. Can you show me what is list comprehension approach?

Comment: @BobHaffner, i meant that the input data frame change between examples. There is inconsistency in the data that we are working with. Even in the OP's example code. I understand the problem.

Comment: @palazzotrain  `df['C'] = [l[-2] for l in df['A']]`  Also, I thought maybe you could index into A like `df['A'].values[:,-2]` but i get an error.  i think its because I'm trying to index into to it like a 2d, but its only a 1d array

Comment: @GeneBurinsky, thanks for you suggested edit

Answer (score 0):

You can define your lambda as a regular function and call it using apply like so:

```
def my_function(x):
    return x[-2]

df['C'] = df['A'].apply(my_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `str` to index from the list but it requires the string lengths to be uniform. You could also use the list comprehension proposed by Bob which is the most robust solution.

```
In [110]: df.A.str.join(',').str[-3]
Out[110]:
0    b
1    g
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Here's a regex solution because this may be more robust to different string lengths and types in the list. Replace `"\w"` if actual list elements are more complex.

```
#create data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']], 'B': [3,5]})

#one step solution:
df['C'] = df.A.str.join(sep=',').str.extract("(\w),\w$", expand=False)

#result:
In [22]: df.C
Out[22]:
0    b
1    g
Name: C, dtype: object
```